# Setting up CardLayout

Tags: java, containers, cardlayout

I am trying to making a game using CardLayout but can't figure out how to do it. I get the error:

```
incompatible types: CardLayout cannot be converted to LayoutManager
       c.setLayout(cardsL);
```

This is how I am creating the Panels:

```
public class RunGame extends JFrame{
    static CardLayout cardsL;
    static Container c;
    public RunGame(){    //constructor
       c=getContentPane();
       cardsL=new CardLayout();
       c.setLayout(cardsL);
       JPanel menuP = new Menu();
       JPanel gameP = new Game();
       c.add("Menu", menuP);
       c.add("Game", gameP);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RunGame a = new RunGame();
        a.setSize(500, 500);
        a.setVisible(true);
        a.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
    }
}
```

However, when I basically do the same thing in a different file, I do not get the error. Code in the other file:

```
public class Card_Layout_Demo extends JFrame{
    static CardLayout cardsL;
    static Container c;

    MyMenuPanel  menuP;  // object of my customized class MyMenuPanel
    MyGamePanel gameP;   // object of my customized class MyGamePanel

    public Card_Layout_Demo(){    //constructor
       c=getContentPane();
       cardsL=new CardLayout();
       c.setLayout(cardsL);
       menuP = new MyMenuPanel();
       gameP = new MyGamePanel();
       c.add("MenuNickName", menuP);
       c.add("GameNickName", gameP);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Card_Layout_Demo a = new Card_Layout_Demo();
        a.setSize(500, 500);
        a.setVisible(true);
        a.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at the `import` statements at the top of the file. You're probably importing a different `CardLayout` class from a different package.

Comment: Note: it's a bad idea to declare the fields `cardsL` and `c` as `static`. They're not static, you'll have different values for different instances of the object, and you don't gain anything from making them `static`.

Comment: I tried your first piece of code and it works. @Erwin Bolwidt is probably right.

Comment: I had a file in the same folder named CardLayout. Thank you, it works now.